# Unknown segmentation fault in C

Tags: c, string, pointers, segmentation-fault

I can not for the love of me tall why I keep getting a segmentation fault(core dump) any help would be appreciated. The goal is for the strmax function to return the largest ASCII value character.

```
#include <stdio.h>

char strmax(char *str) {
  char max = '0';
  while (*str != '\0'){
    if (*str > max){
      max = *str;
    }
  str = str + 1;
  }
      return max;
}

int main(){
  char x;
  char arr[] = {"The end"};
  x = strmax(arr);
  printf("%s\n", x);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try turning on warnings, your format string doesn't match the arguments.

Comment: Compiler warnings for `printf("%s\n", x);`.

Comment: After fixing that, try `char arr[] = {"...!"};` and you'll see a wrong output.

Answer (score 2):

`%s` is for printing *strings* and *a pointer* must be passed.

To print one character by passing the character, use `%c` instead.

Answer (score 0):

`%s` is used when printing *strings*. If you want the char with the largest ASCII value, use`%c`. If you want the ASCII value itself, then do `%d`.